# Average and Sum do not work on anonymous types?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

Sorry if this has already been asked somewhere, but I wasn't able to find it.  It seems that Average and Sum do not work across anonymous types.  I've been trying for a while to get this code to work, with no luck.  The query I'm doing is:

```
var trainingPlan = (from tp in context.TPM_TRAININGPLAN
                    join tpd in context.TPM_TRAININGPLANDELIVERABLES on tp.TRAININGPLANID equals tpd.TRAININGPLANID
                    join t in context.TPM_TASK on tpd.TASKID equals t.TASKID
                    where tp.TPM_PROJECTVERSION.PROJECTID == projectId && tp.TPM_PROJECTVERSION.VERSIONID == versionId && tp.TRAININGPLANTYPE == "prescribed"
                    select new
                    {
                        CourseLength = tp.COURSELENGTHHOUR * 60 + tp.COURSELENGTHMINUTE,
                        DeliveryMethod = tp.TPM_DELIVERYMETHODS.NAME,
                        CourseCode = t.COURSECODE
                    });
```

I now want to take an sum of the CourseLength property, so I do:

```
int sum = trainingPlan.Sum(l => l.CourseLength.Value);
```

However, "sum" ends up being 0.  Same with "Average".  I can clearly see under the debugger that trainingPlan has two items, one with CourseLength = 90 and one with CourseLength = 150.

Does Sum just not work on these types of enumerables?  Thanks!

Comment: `Sum()` most definitely works on anonymous types - especially in this case, when there is no anonymous type as it's being translated into SQL at some point.

Comment: So you're saying it just doesn't work if it's querying through a DB provider?  In that case, can I "query" for everything and then "average" the numbers offline, rather than have the DB do it?

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using (EF, LINQ to SQL, …)? Can you look at the generated SQL?

Comment: Oracle 11.1 and OraDirect - I am unaware of a way to actually look at the generate SQL, but then again I'm not an Oracle expert.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm using Entity Framework.

Comment: @Mike Christensen - no I'm saying that in this case the Sum() operation isn't being performed on an anonymous type at all; it's performed in a DB query because of the fact you're using Linq-2-*something* (it does depend on the provider)

Comment: It looks like the CourseLength is a nullable type... I don't have any experience with LINQ to SQL, but did you try `int sum = trainingPlan.Sum(l => l.CourseLength);`? Or how about `int sum = trainingPlan.Where(l=>l.CourseLength.HasValue).Sum(l => l.CourseLength.Value);`?

Comment: Yup I actually tried both of those before at first, I just decided to simplify the example for the post.  CourseLength is technically an int? type, but my dataset doesn't happen to have any nulls (and would probably crash if it did, since I'm multiplying the numbers but hey I'll fix that later)..

Comment: What version of EF? You might want to add the tag to your question. I just tested it out with EF 4.1 and Sum() and Average() definitely work!

Comment: I'll check on the version tomorrow.  I was just hired on to fix some bugs and add some enhancements to this project, which hasn't been touched by anyone in about a year - So I'm guessing my version is pretty old :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely this could be an issue with the database provider? Since this is a small collection, and you could do trainingPlan.AsEnumerable().Sum. Or, if you are doing multiple calculations, do trainingPlan.ToList(), store that and use it in your calculations.

Comment: Yup, when I convert to ToList() it works! So I guess the Oracle DB provider just doesn't support this sort of query. I really don't like the idea of these calls doing "new queries" anyway so I think this is a better solution regardless of the provider bug. One question, what data type does ToList return? If I want to store ToList() as a separate variable, how do I declare it?  It's a List<> of anonymous types?

Comment: Oh, sorry duh: var list = trainingPlan.ToList();

Comment: Good Answer: I always forget about deferred execution in linq. For info what the projection is Check out : http://tomasp.net/articles/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var stuff = from i in new double[] { 1, 2, 3 }
                    select new {
                        Value = (int) i,
                    };

        var sum = stuff.Sum( s => s.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

so try :

```
select new
                    {
                        CourseLength = (int) tp.COURSELENGTHHOUR * 60 + tp.COURSELENGTHMINUTE,
                        DeliveryMethod = tp.TPM_DELIVERYMETHODS.NAME,
                        CourseCode = t.COURSECODE
                    });

and int sum = trainingPlan.Sum(l => l.CourseLength);
```